# Посчитать частоты символов в строках c#

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо посчитать частоту символов в строках (пример, как это теоретически должно работать)

[image: то, как по итогу должно получится]

Допустим, у меня дана строка с некоторым текстом. Мне необходимо разделить её на слова, длиной *key*, и посчитать частоту символов в каждом столбце.
Я написал код, который делит её на слова, длиной *key*, но дальше не знаю, как можно посчитать (ниже код, который я написал):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int key = 3; //длина слов
        string word = "HELLOWHELOLWH"; //само слово
        Console.WriteLine(word + " = " + word.Length);

        List<string> SecondWords = new List<string>(); //слова, которые чуть позже будут разделены

        int temp = (int)Math.Ceiling(word.Length / (double)key); //количество "частей", на которые нужно поделить слово

        for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) //деление слова на "части"
        {
            if (i == temp - 1)
            {
                if (i * key + 1 == word.Length)
                    SecondWords.Add(word[i * key].ToString());
                if (i * key + 2 == word.Length)
                    SecondWords.Add(word[i * key].ToString() + word[i * key + 1].ToString());
            }
            if (i != temp - 1)
                SecondWords.Add(word[i * key].ToString() + word[i * key + 1].ToString() + word[i * key + 2].ToString());
        }

        foreach (string p in SecondWords) //вывод полученных "частей" слова
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

P.S. Допустим, на данном примере, частоты букв (для 1 столбика) a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, ...., h = 0,6, .... и т.д.

Comment: Создайте массив словарей длиной key, и пишите в эти словари букву как ключ и количество как значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант через LINQ:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)str.Length / wordLen)) // Получим число слов
    .Select(i => str.Substring(i * wordLen, Math.Min(str.Length-i*wordLen,wordLen)).ToCharArray())// Разобьём строку на части нужной длины (последнее слово - остатком)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Select((c,i) => new { index = i, chr = c }))// Разобьём части на символы с запоминанием позиции
    .GroupBy(x => x.index) // Сгруппируем в "слова"
    .Select((x, i) => new { Word = i, letters = x.GroupBy(g => g.chr) }) //Сгруппируем каждое слово посимвольно
    .Select(x => x.letters.Select(l => new { x.Word, l.Key, Count = l.Count() })) //Посчитаем символы
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z'-'A').Select(e => new //Получим алфавит
    {
        x.First().Word,
        Letter = (char)e,
        Rate = (decimal)(x.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Key == e)?.Count??0) / x.Sum(w => w.Count) //Посчитаем рейт
    })).Where(x=>x.Rate>0).ToList() //Выведем все записи с ненулевым рейтом
```

Если нужен весь алфавит (с нулевыми записями) - последнее условие убираем.

Протестить можно тут: https://ideone.com/9QPNjL

Comment: Если тоже самое нужно сделать ещё для русского алфавита - нужно просто изменить 17 строчку? на ".SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range('А', 'Я' - 'А').Select(e => new //Получим алфавит"?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z'-'A').Union(Enumerable.Range('А', 'Я'-'А'))` - алфавит из русских и английских букв. Цифры, маленькие буквы - аналогично (или можно подготовить алфавит в  отдельной строке и не использовать Enumerable.Range)

Comment: Если кому-то нужно: если у вас не отображается частота последней буквы (Z или Я), добавьте +1 в конце (Например, x => Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1), если у вас английский алфавит, то будет выглядеть вот так)

Answer (score 4):

Простейший алгоритм, переводим из 2 мерных координат в одномерные и ищем нужный символ

```
var len = 3; //длина слов
var words = "HELLOWHELOLWH"; //само слово

var dicts = new Dictionary<char, int>[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) dicts[i] = new Dictionary<char, int>();

var totalWords = words.Length / len + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < totalWords; j++)
    {
        var ind = j * len + i;
        if (ind >= words.Length) break;

        var c = words[ind];
        if (dicts[i].ContainsKey(c)) dicts[i][c]++;
        else dicts[i][c] = 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    double total = dicts[i].Values.Sum();
    foreach (var kv in dicts[i]) Console.WriteLine($"column: {i} char: {kv.Key} freq: {kv.Value / total} ({kv.Value} / {total})");
}
```

Результат

```
column: 0 char: H freq: 0.6 (3 / 5)
column: 0 char: L freq: 0.2 (1 / 5)
column: 0 char: O freq: 0.2 (1 / 5)
column: 1 char: E freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
column: 1 char: O freq: 0.25 (1 / 4)
column: 1 char: L freq: 0.25 (1 / 4)
column: 2 char: L freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
column: 2 char: W freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Чисто для галочки, linq вариант

```
var len = 3; //длина слов
var words = "HELLOWHELOLWH"; //само слово

var data = words.Select((x,i)=> (col:i%len, val:x))
    .GroupBy(x=>x.col, x=>x.val)
    .Select(x=>(col:x.Key, data: x.GroupBy(z=>z).Select(z=>(val:z.Key, count:z.Count()))));

foreach (var column in data)
{
    double total = column.data.Sum(z=>z.count);
    foreach (var item in column.data)
        Console.WriteLine($"column: {column.col} char: {item.val} freq: {item.count / total} ({item.count} / {total})");
}
```

Вывод

```
column: 0 char: H freq: 0.6 (3 / 5)
column: 0 char: L freq: 0.2 (1 / 5)
column: 0 char: O freq: 0.2 (1 / 5)
column: 1 char: E freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
column: 1 char: O freq: 0.25 (1 / 4)
column: 1 char: L freq: 0.25 (1 / 4)
column: 2 char: L freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
column: 2 char: W freq: 0.5 (2 / 4)
```