# Как из списка достать уникальные слова отфильтровав слова которые являются дубликатами или подстроками слов?

Tags: c#, list

Допустим, у меня есть `List<>`, в котором есть много разных слов. Нужно в нём найти слова, которые повторяются.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы программа нашла, что слово `"анненский"`, которое встречается в 4 слове и так же `"анненский"`, которое встречается в 5 слове. Далее, убрала все остальные слова и оставила только четвёртое слово без повторов.

Другой пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 слово - "нагибин". 4 слово "нагибиннагибин". Нужно, чтобы осталось только первое слово.

Другой пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 слово - `"алиса"`. 4 слово - `"алисаалиса"`. 5 слово `"алисаалисаалиса"`. Нужно, чтобы осталось только первое слово "`алиса"`.

Comment: Ну и зачем заминусовали? Реально интересная задача.

Comment: @AK задача то интересная, но попыток решения нет. То есть по идее вопрос вообще следовало бы закрыть как учебное задание.

Comment: @tym32167 На днях [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1261104/213987) что-то похожее, такое впечатление, возможно я неправ, что сначала пошёл по пути разбиения слов по частотам, но не зашло, в итоге решил прямо исходную задачу как есть запостить. И вообще, что мешает благородным донам понять задачу так как удобно и предложить изящное решение? :) Но человека не оправдываю, да.

Comment: @AK ничего не мешает, вопрос только в том, будет ли решение ответом к вопросу или решением чего то, что не спрвшивали. Добавил там ответ тоже, там ничего разбивать не пришлось, обычная трансформация из 2 мерных координат в одномерные.

Comment: @AK добавил [linq однострочник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265353/179763), если вам будет интересно глянуть :)

Comment: Да, я раньше спрашивал решение для другой проблемной части. Сейчас возникла проблема с этим моментом. Уже 3-ий день бьюсь над данной проблемой и не могу решить, поэтому написал сюда. Пробовал через сортировку и поиск i-ого слова через foreach, но ничего не получалось. Так же, пробовал разбивать слова на буквы и искать по "длине слова" (если через N-расстояние встречается такая же буква, то... (и т.д.)

Comment: Я ниже прикрепил в комментарии свой вариант, как я до этого пытался реализовать это. Залез сюда, чтобы понять, можно ли как-то "по-умному" это написать

Comment: Не забудьте принять наиболее полезгый ответ. Кстати, не обязательно принимать только тогда, когда вы использовали ответ как решение, можно и просто самый полезный на ваш взгляд.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Типичная задача для структуры данных Trie

```
public class TrieNode
{
    private Dictionary<char, TrieNode> _children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
    private String _payload = null;

    public void Add(String str)
    {
        Add(str, 0);
    }

    private void Add(string str, int ind)
    {
        if (str.Length == ind)
        {
            _payload = str;
            return;
        }

        var c = str[ind];

        if (!_children.TryGetValue(c, out var next))
        {
            next = new TrieNode();
            _children[c] = next;
        }
        next.Add(str, ind + 1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetShortest()
    {
        if (_payload != null) yield return _payload;
        else
            foreach (var v in _children.Values)
                foreach (var ret in v.GetShortest()) yield return ret;
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "цыпа",
    "алиса",
    "цыпацыпа",
    "алисаалиса",
};

var root = new TrieNode();

foreach (var w in list) root.Add(w);

foreach (var ret in root.GetShortest()) Console.WriteLine(ret);
```

Результат

```
цыпа
алиса
```

Подход хорошо работает если много одинаковых слов. Этот подход можно оптимизировать по разному, но в среднем он быстрее всего остального, что можно придумать и кушает чуть больше памяти. Также для симльно длинных слов можно рекурсию заменить на цикл, но для относительно коротких слов это без разницы.

Применительно к вашей задаче, можно не добавлять длинное слово, если его префикс уже был добавлен ранее (или удалять все поддерево если добавляется префикс), что может сэкономить память.

Также эта структура фильтрует дубликаты. А если алфавит слов известен, то можно ещё и результат получить сортированным.

Алгоритм работает с линейной скоростью относительно слов и символов.

Comment: ай, как красиво! Положил себе в копилку - очень хороший пример. Жаль, что нельзя два плюсика поставить.

Comment: tym32167 - Шикарное решение! Спасибо!

Comment: Класс! Добавлю лишь [ссылку](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx) для интересующихся с описанием алгоритма и сценариев использования.

Answer (score 3):

Классический подход к фильтрации дубликатов - это `HashSet`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(list);
list = set.ToList();
```

Всё!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это половина ответа, тут скучно всё. Вторая часть - как определить, что слово написано два-три раза подряд.

Вторая часть концентрируется на том, является ли строка2 размноженной 1..n раз строкой1:

```
private bool IsDupString(string sample1, string sample2)
{
    if (sample1.Length == sample2.Length)
        return string.Equals(sample1, sample2);

    // to guarantee that sample1 is less than sample2
    if (sample1.Length > sample2.Length)
        return IsDupString(sample2, sample1);

    int ratio = TryGetRatio(sample1.Length, sample2.Length);

    if (ratio == 0)
        return false;

    var i = 0;
    while (i < sample1.Length)
    {
        var ch = sample1[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < ratio; j++)
        {
            var pos = i + (sample1.Length) * j;
            if (sample2[pos] != ch)
                return false;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}

private int TryGetRatio(int length1, int length2)
{
    double delta = 0.0001;
    double ratio1 = (double)length2 / length1;
    double ratio2 = length2 / length1;

    if (Math.Abs(ratio1 - ratio2) > delta)
        return 0;

    return (int)ratio2;
}
```

Можете запустить на нескольких примерах, чтобы проверить работу. Возможно,  можно написать проще, я не думал об этом, просто написал прямолинейный алгоритм.

А вообще собираем вместе - получаем нужный ответ:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "цыпа",
    "алиса",
    "цыпацыпа",
    "алисаалиса",
};

var set = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(set.Any(x => IsDupString(item, x)))
        continue;
        
    if(!set.Contains(item))
        set.Add(item);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остался небольшой момент, что делать если в списке сначала встретится "алисаалиса" раньше чем просто "алиса", но мне кажется, что допилить текущий алгоритм будет несложно. И нет, сортировать нет смысла, можно проще.

Answer (score 3):

Для каждого слова `s` построить его сжатое представление в виде s = p<sup>q</sup> с помощью [z-функции](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/z_function): для строки `s` длиной `n` найдём первую позицию `i` такую, что `i + z[i] = n`, и при этом `n % i == 0`. Тогда строку `s` можно сжать до строки длины `i`, и `q = n / i`

Например, 'папапа' => 'па'<sup>3</sup>

Сложить в map сжатые строки в виде пар `(string:List<int>)`, где string - сжатая строка p, а количество повторов q добавляется в список.

Для каждого ключа `p` с длиной списка более 1 проверяем, являются ли бОльшие `q` кратными наименьшему из списка. Если да - выводим `p` с наименьшим количеством повторов.

Если нет - разбиваем список на группы, содержащие наименьшие делители и кратные им (если есть). Например, для `'па':{2,3,5,6,9}` получаем 'папа', 'папапа' и  'папапапапа'

Answer (score 2):

Я Вам предложу очень простой алгоритм, который, правда, может свести весь большой список буквально к алфавиту.

0. Исходный список назовем просто list
1. Соритруем слова по длинне. В начале будут самые короткие. Назовем этот список list_sorted
2. Заводим Dictionary, я назову его просто dictionary. Начинаем с начала отсортированного списка вставлять слова в dictinary - естественно, без повторений.
3. При каждой вставке пробегаемся по списку list_sorted (или просто list) и выкидываем из него все слова, в котрых встречается очередное вставляемое в dictinary слово в качестве подстроки.

Всё.

Заметьте, что если у Вас встретится в спсике слово "и", то "или", "иллюзорный" и "имманул" в кончательный спсиок уже не попадут. Вам именно так надо?

То есть, уточните:

Если слово "алисаалисаалиса" встретися в исходном списке раньше слова "алиса" - то оба должны остаться в списке? если это так - просто не надо сортировать исходный спиок по длинне слов.

Могу добавить код, но просто напишиет в комментариях, соответствует ли алгоритм задаче...

Comment: Примерно похожий алгоритм придумал, но без сортировки - просто считаю, можно ли повторяя одно слово несколько раз получить другое. И я взял HashSet, мне кажется, что Dictionary здесь избыточен - что будем хранить в TValue?

Comment: @AK - абсолютно верное замечание, не нужен :-) Я приудмал сортировку по длинне как оптимизацию - но там в конце ответа есть вопрос к автору вопроса - насчет того, важен ли порядок слов в исходном наборе. Поставил плюсик :-)

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал всё-таки оставить свой вариант "кода". Банальный перебор слов. Не уверен, что это правильно, но это, вроде, работает.

```
var list = new List<string>()
            {
                "енн",
                "ннннн",
                "еннкнн",
                "анненский",
                "нннн",
                "анненскийанненский",
                "анненскийанненскийанненский",
                "ннйнннн",
                "иннннокнн",
            };

            List<string> newList = new List<string>(); //лист, где будут "правильные слова"

            string tempWord = ""; //временная переменная для поиска слова
            list.Sort();
            foreach (var item in list) //логика такая - если данный элемент, который представлен в List, при добавлении себя к себе, существует к List, то его добавляем в "правильный лист"
            {
                tempWord = item + item;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (tempWord == list[i]) //если "двойное" слово существует в List, то добавляю его в другой List
                    {
                        newList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var i in newList) //вывод нового листа
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```