# Оптимизация кода (поиск повторяющихся элементов в тексте)

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Как можно оптимизировать данный код? На довольно-таки длинные тексты он крайне долго работает.
Суть задачи: нужно найти повторяющиеся элементы в тексте и посчитать расстояние между ними.
Например:
*АБВ*ГДЙАУА*АБВ*
И так по всему тексту ищутся вот такие "слова" длиной от 3 до 16 символов

```
for (int maxLength = 3; maxLength <= 16; maxLength++) //maxLength - длина подСЛОВ, которые ищутся в ЗАШИФРОВАННОМ слове (3 - ааа, 4 - аааа, 5 - ааааа)
            {
                //поиск повторяющихся N-х элементов подряд (maxLength)
                for (int i = 0; i <= newWORD.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i < newWORD.Length - (maxLength - 1))
                    {
                        string b = ""; //первое подСлово
                        for (int qq = 0; qq < maxLength; qq++)
                            b += newWORD[i + qq].ToString();

                        for (int j = 0; j <= newWORD.Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (j < newWORD.Length - (maxLength - 1))
                            {
                                string c = ""; //второе подСлово
                                for (int q = 0; q < maxLength; q++)
                                    c += newWORD[j + q].ToString();

                                if ((b == c) && (i != j))
                                {
                                    //вывод повторяющихся элементов
                                    //Console.WriteLine(b + "[" + i + "]" + " Повторяется с " + c + "[" + j + "]");

                                    for (double l = 4; l <= 75; l++) //длина ключа ОТ и ДО (4 до 75)
                                    {
                                        if ((j - i) > 0) //если число положительное (проверка)
                                        {
                                            double Check = (j - i) / l; //и выполняется условие
                                            if (Check % 1 == 0) //и остаток от деления равен 0
                                            {
                                                int l_int = Convert.ToInt32(l);
                                                if (KeyLength.ContainsKey(l_int))
                                                    KeyLength[l_int]++;
                                                else
                                                    KeyLength[l_int] = 1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Ссылка на программу - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McXZ_gPWvvMxJ7iUGFEhTPhhbZKXbWfb/view

Скриншот с конечным результатом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что то я не сильно понял, что это за ключ длины 14, который 511 раз встречется? У меня соотношение ключей и частот вышло [вот таким](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCFsP.png).

Comment: Также не ясно, может ли один ключ быть частью другого. Например ABABA - вы тут видите 2 ключа длиной 3 `ABA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, добавил несколько, на первый взгляд очевидных оптимизаций.

Вот это место `c += newWORD[j + q].ToString();` - самое медленное у вас. При добавлении символа, создается новая строка с этим символом, в потом в `c` присваивается новая строка с приклеенным символом. Всё потому что строки C# не изменяемые, то есть данный цикл для длины слова в 10 символов создает 20 строк в памяти, когда можно обойтись всего одной.

```cs
string newWORD = resultKeyWord.Replace(" ", "");

for (int maxLength = 3; maxLength <= 16; maxLength++) //maxLength - длина подСЛОВ, которые ищутся в ЗАШИФРОВАННОМ слове (3 - ааа, 4 - аааа, 5 - ааааа)
{
    //поиск повторяющихся N-х элементов подряд (maxLength)
    for (int i = 0; i <= newWORD.Length - maxLength; i++)
    {
        string b = newWORD.Substring(i, maxLength);

        for (int j = i + 1; j <= newWORD.Length - maxLength; j++)
        {
            string c = newWORD.Substring(j, maxLength);

            if (b == c)
            {
                for (int l = 4; l <= 75; l++) //длина ключа ОТ и ДО (4 до 75)
                {
                    if ((j - i) % l == 0) //и остаток от деления равен 0
                    {
                        KeyLength[l] = KeyLength.TryGetValue(l, out int value) ? value + 1 : 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Осталось {16 - maxLength}");
}
```

Работает в 15-20 раз быстрее, чем исходный вариант в режиме отладки.

По идее, можно еще быстрее, но в рамках старого .NET Framework у меня не меняя подхода к реализации вряд-ли получится. Нужен минимум .NET Core 3.1.

Получилось бы что-то такое

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> newWORD = resultKeyWord.Replace(" ", "");

for (int maxLength = 3; maxLength <= 16; maxLength++) //maxLength - длина подСЛОВ, которые ищутся в ЗАШИФРОВАННОМ слове (3 - ааа, 4 - аааа, 5 - ааааа)
{
    //поиск повторяющихся N-х элементов подряд (maxLength)
    for (int i = 0; i <= newWORD.Length - maxLength; i++)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<char> b = newWORD[i..(i + maxLength)];

        for (int j = i + 1; j <= newWORD.Length - maxLength; j++)
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<char> c = newWORD[j..(j + maxLength)];

            if (b.SequenceEqual(c))
            {
                for (int l = 4; l <= 75; l++) //длина ключа ОТ и ДО (4 до 75)
                {
                    if ((j - i) % l == 0) //и остаток от деления равен 0
                    {
                        KeyLength[l] = KeyLength.TryGetValue(l, out int value) ? value + 1 : 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Осталось {16 - maxLength}");
}
```

Что работает еще раза в полтора быстрее, чем предыдущий вариант.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я так понимаю, у меня какая-то старая версия Net Core и нужно обновить её?

Comment: @Frehzy у вас проект создан для .NET Framework, пересоздайте заново для .NET 5.

Comment: @Frehzy если быть точнее, то на моем компе финальный код 267мс, а ваш изначальный 15498мс. В релизном билде. То есть разница в скорости на релизном билде в 58 раз.

Comment: @Frehzy добавил еще одну оптимизацию в обе версии кода. Теперь еще быстрее стало.

Answer (score 3):

Сам поиск дубликатов делатся элементарно. В этом поможет структура данных Trie. Например, вот код узла

```
public class TrieNode
{
    public int level;
    public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
    public HashSet<int> endings = new HashSet<int>();
    
    public TrieNode(int level)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void Add(string str, int ind)
    {
        if (str.Length == ind || level > 16)
            return;     
        
        endings.Add(ind);
        
        var c = str[ind];

        if (!children.TryGetValue(c, out var next))
        {
            next = new TrieNode(this.level + 1);
            children[c] = next;
        }
        next.Add(str, ind + 1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetDuplicates(string initialString)
    {
        if (this.level > 2 && this.endings.Count > 1)
        {
            var ind = this.endings.First();
            var start = ind - level;
            var ret = initialString.Substring(start, level);
            yield return ret;
        }

        foreach (var item in children.Values)       
            foreach (var s in item.GetDuplicates(initialString))            
                yield return s;
    }
}
```

Как можно видеть, я сохраняю индекс конца слова в узел, а уровень вложенности узла говорит о длине слова. Этой информации достаточно, чтобы найти слово в тексте.

Использовать код можно так

```
string str =    "ЧИРТЖ .... ";  
var root = new TrieNode(0); 

for(int i=0; i<str.Length-2; i++)   
    root.Add(str, i);

var dups = root.GetDuplicates(str);

foreach (var dup in dups.OrderBy(z => z))
    Console.WriteLine(dup);
```

В результате получим все повторяюзие слова

```
АЛН
АТХ
АУР
АУЯ
АХЗ
...
```

Так как у нас слово имеет ограниченную длину в 16 символов, то можно принять сложность алгоритма как линейную (хотя вот это `dups.OrderBy(z => z)` уже в основном коде будет за O(nlogn) от числа дубликатов работать).

Минус подхода - кушает много памяти, особенно если стрка болшая, а дубликатов мало.

Как у автора считается расстояние между словами для меня осталось загадкой, но в моем коде, имея индексы конца слов, расстояние считается элементарно.

Comment: Надо бенчмаркнуть, но да, тот код, где я спаны использую, вообще не кушает память (то есть не спавнит ни одного объекта), следовательно даже при большом количестве итераций отрабатывает оно весьма шустро.

Comment: @aepot ну ваш вариант работает за квадрат, но не ест памяти. Мой линейный, но ест. Я думаю, разница в подходах будет видна на тексте в пару-тройку мегабайт.

Comment: @aepot хотя мне тут в голову мысль пришла, что даже большие блоки текста можно пилить на части и обрабатывать по отдельности (они только должны накладываться друг на друга на 16 символов), тогда можно обойти ограничение памяти для моего варианта. А вот у вам на больших массивах будет тормозить.

Comment: @aepot кстати, так как у нас используется GC, то сам процесс выделения памяти в .NET считается недорогой операцией. По крайней мере по сравнению с C++, так как, если я верно помню, GC изначально выделяет себе какой то пул в памяти, и выделение новой памяти для него сродни перемещению указателя.

Comment: Ну дорогой - не дорогой, я не знаю, но разница между спанами и строками примерно в 2 раза по производительности. Ща, я еще нашел у себя косяк, поправлю код.

Comment: @aepot я согласен, что лушче память не выделять, чем выделять :) Я про то, что  в вашем случае спаны делают алгоритм быстрее, но не делают асимптотически быстрее.

Comment: Ну здесь из двух зол выбирать приходится, где главное зло - это тормоза на популярном наборе данных. А на эталоне из вопроса, я завтра погоняю ваше и своё, если не лень будет. :)

Comment: А какой размер эталона?

Answer (score 0):

Постройте суффиксный массив, на его основе постройте массив LCP (longest common prefixes, самые длинные префиксы соседних суффиксов).

Вот элементы последнего массива со значениями  `от 3 до 16` укажут на искомое.

Comment: посмотрел видео об LCP и как-то не очень понял, как его можно впихнуть сюда (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MD4jY5sFGzw)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265274/373567 - это вы имели в виду?

Comment: Там работа с листом. У меня немного другая задача - поиск слов длиной от 3 до 16 по всему тексту. Другими словами, сначала нужно найти все слова длиной 3 повторяющиеся, потом 4, 5, ..., 16 и посчитать расстояние между ними

Comment: `довольно-таки длинные тексты` - какая длина актуальна?

Comment: @aepot Нет, не trie, это другие структуры данных

Comment: @aepot прикрутил trie :D