# Медленно работает алгоритм поиска слов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, рекурсия

Есть матрица букв (nхn):
`А Р А Г`
`Е Ж М Б`
`Л Г Н Т`
`А О Р И`
Нужно вывести все слова, которые можно получить соединением соседних букв (соединять можно по горизонтали, вертикали и диагонали. Повторно использовать буквы в одном слове нельзя). Количество элементов в одном "сочетании" может быть любым (от 2х до n^2ти):
АРАБ, ЖАРА, ЕЖ, РИТМ, АЛГОРИТМ...
Придумал вот такой код. Используем графы:
Есть классы:

```
//Вершина графа = одна буква  
public class Point //record работает медленнее
    {
        private int x;
        public int X { get => x; set => x = value; }
        private int y;
        public int Y { get => y; set => y = value; }
        private char val;
        public char Val { get => val; set => val = value; }
        public Point(int x, int y, char val)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Val = val;
        }
    }
```

```
// Ребро графа
    internal class Edge
    {
        public Point From { get; set; }
        public Point To { get; set; }
        public Edge(Point from, Point to)
        {
            From = from; 
            To = to;
        }
    }
```

```
// Сам граф
    internal class Graph
    {
        public Point[,] Points;
        public List<Edge> Edges;
        public void AddEdges(Point from, Point to)
        {
            Edges.Add(new Edge(from, to));
        }

        public Graph(Point[,] points, List<Edge> edges)
        {
            this.Points = points ;
            this.Edges = edges ;
        }


        public List<Point> GetPointsList(Point point)
        // Вернуть лист смежных вершин
        {
           // var selectedEdges = Edges.Where(p => p.From == point); через LINQ медленнее на 5 секунд
            var result = new List<Point>();

            foreach (var edge in Edges)
            {
                if (edge.From == point)
                {
                    result.Add(edge.To);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

```
// Найденное слово. Состоит из последовательности вершин графа и его строкового представления. Представлено классом Answer
    internal class Answer
    {
        public string Word { get; set; }
        public List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
        public Answer(string word, List<Point> points)
        {
            Word = word;
            Points = points;
        }
    }
```

Выполнение программы:
заполнили матрицу

```
Point[,] charArr  = new Point[4,4];
```

Создали граф:

```
Graph SlovoGraph = new Graph(charArr, FormAges.CreateEdges(charArr));
```

Метод CreateEdges заполняет все ребра графа (чтоб не заполнять вручную):

```
         public static List<Edge> CreateEdges(Point[,] Arr)
        {
            List<Edge> edges = new List<Edge>();
            Point lastPoint;
            int rows = Arr.GetLength(0);
            int cols = Arr.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    {
                        lastPoint = Arr[i, j];
                        if (lastPoint.X - 1 >= 0 && lastPoint.Y - 1 >= 0) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i - 1, j - 1]));
                        if (lastPoint.X - 1 >= 0) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i - 1, j]));
                        if (lastPoint.X - 1 >= 0 && lastPoint.Y + 1 < cols) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i - 1, j + 1]));
                        if (lastPoint.Y - 1 >= 0) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i, j - 1]));
                        if (lastPoint.Y + 1 < rows) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i, j + 1]));
                        if (lastPoint.X + 1 < rows && lastPoint.Y - 1 >= 0) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i + 1, j - 1]));
                        if (lastPoint.X + 1 < rows) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i + 1, j]));
                        if (lastPoint.X + 1 < rows && lastPoint.Y + 1 < cols) edges.Add(new Edge(Arr[i, j], Arr[i + 1, j + 1]));
                    }
                }
            }
            return edges;
        }
```

Далее вызываем метод поиска:

```
List<Answer> answerList = new List<Answer>();  
answerList = WordClass.Find(SlovoGraph, wordsList);
```

В WordClass.Find будет использоваться метод расширения, который создает дубликат листа с добавленным элементом (он использует 6% времени поиска слов):

```
    internal static class ListExtension
    {
        public static List<T> CloneAndAdd<T>(this List<T> source, T a)
        {
            List<T> tempList = new List<T>(source.Count+1);
            tempList = source.GetRange(0, source.Count);
            tempList.Add(a);
            return tempList;
        }
    }
```

Метод WordClass.Find:

```
   internal static class WordClass
    {
        public static List<List<Point>> VariantCollection = new(); // хранит все получившиеся варианты
        public static List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>(); //коллекция ответов
        
        public static List<Answer> Find(Graph slovoGraph, List<string> source) 
// source - лист строк всех русских слов в алфавитном порядке. Загружается из .txt
        {
            Point[,] Arr = slovoGraph.Points;
            int Rows = Arr.GetLength(0);
            int Cols = Arr.GetLength(1);
            string ComposedWord;
            bool NotContainPoint;

            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
                {
                    {
                        VariantCollection.Add(new List<Point> { Arr[i, j] });
                        FindFunc(VariantCollection.Last());

                    }
                }
            }

            void FindFunc(List<Point> points)
            {
                var NextPointList = slovoGraph.GetPointsList(points.Last()); //выбираем все смежные вершины у текущей буквы. Потребляет 27% времени выполнения алгоритма!
                foreach (var NextPoint in NextPointList)
                {
                    NotContainPoint = !VariantCollection.Last().Contains(NextPoint); // Потребляет 25% времени выполнения алгоритма!
                    if (NotContainPoint) // если эта буква в слове еще не использовалась
                    {
                        VariantCollection.Add(points.CloneAndAdd(NextPoint)); //добавляем букву
                        ComposedWord = ComposeWord(VariantCollection.Last()); //составляем слово

                        if (source.BinarySearch(ComposedWord) >= 0) //если слово есть в словаре. Потребляет 11% времени выполнения алгоритма
                        {
                           Answers.Add(new Answer(ComposedWord, VariantCollection.Last())); //добавляем найденное слово в лист ответов
                        }
                        FindFunc(VariantCollection.Last()); // вызываем рекурсивно функцию добавив к цепочке следующую букву
                        VariantCollection.RemoveAt(VariantCollection.Count - 1);
                    }
                }

            }

            string ComposeWord (List<Point> lp) // потребляет 7% времени выполнения алгоритма
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(25);
                foreach (Point p in lp) sb.Append(p.Val);
                return sb.ToString();
                
            }

            return Answers;
        }



    }
```

Матрицу 3х3 выполняет недолго, а вот 4х4 уже около минуты. 5х5 - не дождался завершения.
Подскажите, где что-то можно написать более грамотно, чтоб повысить скорость выполнения?

Comment: Как это запустить, чтобы проверить производительность? Как проверяется, что слово найдено? Где взять список слов на проверку?

Comment: Как я понял вы порождаете все последовательность букв из матрицы и затем проверяете их на наличие в списке слов. Это будет работать долго так как вы порождаете много длинных комбинаций, которые можно было бы отбросить, грубо говоря, глядя на первые два символа. Сделайте trie из словаря. В процессе поиска на графе сверяйтесь с трие и прекращайте поиск если такого префикса нет.

Comment: Дайте список слов и пример матрицы 5x5, а то непонятно, как решать проблему, которую невозможно воспроизвести. Нужен воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Матрица - это уже один из вариантов представления графа, где смежные ячейки сязаны между собой. Потому переводя матрицу в список смежности вы просто себе накидываете проблем, не получая ничего взамен.

Comment: Исходники лежат на гите: https://github.com/BeyfusYakov/SlovoZaSlovo
Список слов лежит там же в файле russian_nouns.txt

Comment: Сразу что видно, это Framework 4.8, он медленный. Пересоздайте проект под .NET 6 или новее.

Answer (score 5):

Задачка называется Boogle ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%BB)), довольно популярная. Вот, например, [она на литкоде](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/). Также встречается как домашка к курсу по алгоритмам от Стенфорда ([часть1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1), [часть2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part2))

Суть в том, что у вас есть матрица букв и набор слов и нужно узнать, какие из слов можно составить на этой матрице.

Задчка довольно легко решается. Для начала пилим класс Trie (префиксное дерево) куда сложим все данные нам слова

```
private class TrieNode
{
    private string word = null;
    private TrieNode[] nodes = new TrieNode[26];
    
    public void Add(string str, int ind){
        if (str.Length == ind) {
            word = str;
            return;
        }
        var c = str[ind];
        var cind = c - 'a';
        if (nodes[cind] == null) nodes[cind] = new TrieNode();
        nodes[cind].Add(str, ind+1);
    }
}
```

Я использую массив на 26 элементов потому что задача изначально про буквы на англ языке, но вы настраивайте как хотите, можете хоть на хештаблице сделать trie вместо словаря ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265274/179763)) - разница небольшая.

После загоняем слова в Trie

```
    var root = new TrieNode();
    foreach(var w in words) root.Add(w, 0);
```

Потом сделаем карту использованных букв (ведь каждую букву 1 раз можно пользовать)

```
    var usageMap = new bool[board.Length, board[0].Length];
```

Добавим в Trie метод, который просто рекурсивно найдет все совпадения слов в trie и в матрице

```
    public void FindWords(char[][] board, int i, int j, bool[,] usage, HashSet<string> ret){
        if (word != null) ret.Add(word);
        
        if (i < 0 || i >= board.Length) return;
        if (j < 0 || j >= board[i].Length) return;
        
        if (usage[i,j]) return;         
        
        usage[i,j] = true;
        
        var c = board[i][j];
        var ind = c - 'a';
        
        var node = nodes[ind];
        if (node != null){
            node.FindWords(board, i+1, j, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i-1, j, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i, j+1, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i, j-1, usage, ret);
        }           
        
        usage[i,j] = false;         
    }
```

Обычный бектрекинг, ничего особенного.

Ну и запуск всей этой красоты

```
    var ret = new HashSet<string>();

    for(int i=0; i<board.Length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<board[i].Length; j++){
            root.FindWords(board, i, j, usageMap, ret);
        }
    }       
    
    return ret.ToList();
```

Вот и всё.

Полностью моё решение на литкоде выглядит так

```
public class Solution
{
    public IList<string> FindWords(char[][] board, string[] words)
    {
        var ret = new HashSet<string>();
        var root = new TrieNode();
        foreach(var w in words) root.Add(w, 0);
        
        var usageMap = new bool[board.Length, board[0].Length];
        
        for(int i=0; i<board.Length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<board[i].Length; j++){
                root.FindWords(board, i, j, usageMap, ret);
            }
        }       
        
        return ret.ToList();
    }
    
    private class TrieNode
    {
        private string word = null;
        private TrieNode[] nodes = new TrieNode[26];
        
        public void Add(string str, int ind){
            if (str.Length == ind) {
                word = str;
                return;
            }
            var c = str[ind];
            var cind = c - 'a';
            if (nodes[cind] == null) nodes[cind] = new TrieNode();
            nodes[cind].Add(str, ind+1);
        }
        
        public void FindWords(char[][] board, int i, int j, bool[,] usage, HashSet<string> ret){
            if (word != null) ret.Add(word);
            
            if (i < 0 || i >= board.Length) return;
            if (j < 0 || j >= board[i].Length) return;
            
            if (usage[i,j]) return;         
            
            usage[i,j] = true;
            
            var c = board[i][j];
            var ind = c - 'a';
            
            var node = nodes[ind];
            if (node != null){
                node.FindWords(board, i+1, j, usage, ret);
                node.FindWords(board, i-1, j, usage, ret);
                node.FindWords(board, i, j+1, usage, ret);
                node.FindWords(board, i, j-1, usage, ret);
            }           
            
            usage[i,j] = false;         
        }
    }
}
```

Поскольку у вас доступна еще и диагональ (на литкоде только горизонтали/вертикали), то вам просто при выборе следующей клетки тут

```
            node.FindWords(board, i+1, j, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i-1, j, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i, j+1, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i, j-1, usage, ret);
```

Можно добавить еще диагональных вариантов, типа так

```
            node.FindWords(board, i+1, j+1, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i-1, j-1, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i+1, j-1, usage, ret);
            node.FindWords(board, i-1, j+1, usage, ret);
```

Comment: Поднажал, выжал 1,2 секунды из алгоритма автора, но это предел или почти предел.

Comment: можете попробовать список смежности хранить в виде словаря, чтобы каждый раз не ходить по всем ребрам тут `GetPointsList`. Ну и вместо двоичного поиска использовать хешсет. Просто как вариант =)

Comment: да я уже всё сделал это, закешировано всё что можно https://pastebin.com/KygLcZYi

Comment: Я просто добавил hashset в ваш вариант и получил прирост x2 https://pastebin.com/M025zW6g

Comment: Неплохо, спасибо!

Comment: Есть у данного алгоритма один недостаток: каждый раз делая "шаг назад" в board'е и обнаруживая что (word != null) он снова и снова делает ret.Add(word) (добавляет тоже самое слово). HashSet с дубликатами, конечно, успешно борется...

Comment: @ЯковБейфусь если оптимизировать дальше, можно использованные слова занулить в дереве или даже изъять использованные поддеревья. Асимптотика не изменится, но в случаях с кучей дубликатов будет чуть шустрей работать. Но это уже микрооптимизации.